# Take CSS style values from other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I have two entires for a navbar in my custom CSS, one for the bar as it normally is, and one for the affixed version:

```
.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

#menubar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

They both look similar however the affixed bar looks only slightly different, like background colour is the same but lacks the same shading navbar has when it is not affixed, I've noticed slight differences between if I use bootstraps affix plugin for other things like nag pills to - the text just seems... slightly off and some shading is sometimes not present. Is there a way I can alter the entry of #menubar.affix, such that it get all the same settings as the original bar (including the defaults set by bootstrap) + the other stuff I've got in there such as the altered 'position' variable, z-index and so on?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: sticky ? is that new positionning ? :)

Comment: Holy mackerel, it is!